# Angular 6 - Display variable on URL

Tags: angular, typescript, url, web, angular6

I am trying to solve a problem here.

I need to display a variable on the URL of my Angular App like this:

If `variable` is for example `test` I want to display the URL as `localhost:xxxx/test` and if the `variable` is changed to `something` the URL should be `localhost:xxxx/something` . I have read the Angular documentation but I was unable to find a related section, it's always about parsing data from the URL not injecting data to it.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: You should [re-read the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-definition-with-a-parameter).

Comment: It's still unclear to me how this works. An actual example would be more helpful than row docs.

Comment: I understand, but I'm sorry, we're not here to teach you Angular basics. You should try it yourself, and if you encounter an issue, then you post a question here. Besides, the examples there are well explained, and they usually provide a stackblitz to let you test it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a dynamic parameter in your route definition, for example :

```
{ path: 'xxxx/:myVar', component: MyComponent }
```

and then you use the router to navigate into your component :

```
this.router.navigate(['/xxxx', 'test'])
```

or you use links into your template

```
<a href="" [routerLink]="['/xxxx', 'something']"
```